# How to install Chrome to a custom location?

Tags: 15.04, google-chrome

How can I install Google Chrome to a custom location, instead of its default `usr/bin`?

And where does Chrome keep user settings?

Comment: In `~/.config/google-chrome`, usually.

Comment: @muru So I cannot??? Or I can but it's not advised to change default location?

Comment: You can, it's not advised. For one thing, you'll have to repeat whatever you did each time an upgrade happens.

Comment: You can use symlinks and there will be no problems